# Why does make-counter procedure contains two lambda definition?

Tags: scheme, closures, lisp, counter

I'm trying to understand the scheme code of make-counter procedure. It's a higher order procedure (a procedure outputs another procedure) and I'm stuck with it.

```
(define make-counter
  (lambda (n)
    (lambda () 
      (set! n (+ n 1))
      n)))

(define ca (make-counter 0))
(ca)
(ca)
```

This outputs 1 and 2 respectively as expected. Why do we need 2 nested procedures here? What are their functions individually?

I'd be appreciated if someone explains in details. Thanks from now on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indented properly, this is:

```
(define make-counter
  (lambda (n)
    (lambda ()
      (set! n (+ n 1))
      n)))
```

By the way, you can use a different syntax:

```
(define (make-counter n)
  (lambda ()
    (set! n (+ n 1))
    n))
```

`make-counter` is a function that accepts a number `n` and returns an object called *closure*, which acts like a function but contains a state. Different invocations of  `make-counter` will produce different closures, even when given the same `n` in argument. A closure can be called using the function-call syntax, as you experimented.

When you call the closure, the code that is contained within is executed. In your example, the closure accepts zero arguments, and mutates the variable named `n`. Again, the binding from `n` to a value is local to the closure and different for all instances of counters. But inside a particular counter, `n` always refer to the same memory location.

A call to the `set!` function changes what `n` evaluates to, and replaces the previous value with `(+ n 1)`, incrementing the local counter variable.

Comment: `set!` doesn't return the new value (at least on Chicken. I'm not sure if other Schemes work differently).

Comment: @jkiiski You're right, I didn't see the `n` in the original question and assumed wrongly that `set!` returned the value. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot. I forgot that objects are like procedures in scheme and now understood.